# Abysmal performance using DECRYPTBYKEY in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, encryption

I'm looking at a query that has relatively complex relationship with other tables. Here's what my original query looks like:

```
SELECT  
            SE_CUS_DELIVERY.RECEIPT_NAME,
            SE_CUS_DELIVERY.ORDER_PHONE,
            SE_CUS_DELIVERY.ORDER_ZIP,
            SE_CUS_DELIVERY.ORDER_ADDR,
            ISNULL(SE_CUS_DELIVERY.DELIV_QTY,SRCHGT.CREQTY),
            SE_CUS_DELIVERY.ORDER_HAND

FROM        LC_OUT_REQUEST_DETAIL   ,
            SE_INVENTORY    ,
            SE_CUSTOMER         ,
            SRCHGT          ,
            SE_CUS_DELIVERY         

WHERE       
    LC_OUT_REQUEST_DETAIL.TOTDATE   =   '20140203'
AND   LC_OUT_REQUEST_DETAIL.IO_GB   =   '021'


AND LC_OUT_REQUEST_DETAIL.LOCCD >=  'A0000'

... A lot of additional joins here

group by SRCHGT.CRDATE + SRCHGT.CRESEQ + SRCHGT.CRESEQ_SEQ +  SE_CUS_DELIVERY.DELIV_SEQ ,
            SE_CUS_DELIVERY.RECEIPT_NAME ,
            SE_CUS_DELIVERY.ORDER_PHONE ,
            SE_CUS_DELIVERY.ORDER_ZIP   ,
            SE_CUS_DELIVERY.ORDER_ADDR ,
            ISNULL(SE_CUS_DELIVERY.DELIV_QTY,SRCHGT.CREQTY) ,
            ... Also a lot of group by's following here
order by LC_OUT_REQUEST_DETAIL.TOTDATE,   
            LC_OUT_REQUEST_DETAIL.TOT_NO asc,
            LC_OUT_REQUEST_DETAIL.TOT_NO_SEQ
```

To my surprise, it takes about a second to retrieve more than 10,000 rows.

Nevertheless, I've encrypted data in some columns that contains sensitive data, and I modify my select query like so to get the original value:

```
open Symmetric Key Sym_Key_TestEnc
    decryption by certificate Cert_Test
    with password = 'somepasswordhere'

GO

    SELECT  
                DECRYPTBYKEY(SE_CUS_DELIVERY.RECEIPT_NAME),
                DECRYPTBYKEY(SE_CUS_DELIVERY.ORDER_PHONE),
                DECRYPTBYKEY(SE_CUS_DELIVERY.ORDER_ZIP),
                DECRYPTBYKEY(SE_CUS_DELIVERY.ORDER_ADDR),

                ISNULL(SE_CUS_DELIVERY.DELIV_QTY,SRCHGT.CREQTY),

                DECRYPTBYKEY(SE_CUS_DELIVERY.ORDER_HAND)

    FROM        LC_OUT_REQUEST_DETAIL,
                SE_INVENTORY    ,
                SE_CUSTOMER ,
                SRCHGT      ,
                SE_CUS_DELIVERY         

    WHERE       
        LC_OUT_REQUEST_DETAIL.TOTDATE   =   '20140203'
    AND   LC_OUT_REQUEST_DETAIL.IO_GB   =   '021'


    AND LC_OUT_REQUEST_DETAIL.LOCCD >=  'A0000'
    AND LC_OUT_REQUEST_DETAIL.LOCCD <=  'A9999'

    AND LC_OUT_REQUEST_DETAIL.MAT_CD    =   SE_INVENTORY.MAT_CD
    AND LC_OUT_REQUEST_DETAIL.JCOLOR    =   SE_INVENTORY.JCOLOR
    ....

    group by SRCHGT.CRDATE + SRCHGT.CRESEQ + SRCHGT.CRESEQ_SEQ +  SE_CUS_DELIVERY.DELIV_SEQ ,
                SE_CUS_DELIVERY.RECEIPT_NAME ,
                SE_CUS_DELIVERY.ORDER_PHONE ,
                SE_CUS_DELIVERY.ORDER_ZIP   ,
                SE_CUS_DELIVERY.ORDER_ADDR ,
                .......

    GO          


    Close Symmetric key Sym_Key_TestEnc
```

Now the performance is abysmal. I've been running the same query for more than 5 minutes and it still does not complete.

According to the [MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181860.aspx), there shouldn't be much issues performance wise

> Symmetric encryption and decryption is relatively fast, and is
>   suitable for working with large amounts of data.

Which leads me to think that I must be doing something wrong. Or MSDN is lying to me, but that's probably not the case.

Is there a way to optimize the data decryption in this process?

Comment: Any updates on this? Were you able to improve the performance?